# ArrayList ClassCastException with extended object

Tags: java, inheritance, arraylist, classcastexception

I don't know exactly how to word this title, but here is the problem

I have an `ArrayList` of Object B

Object B extends Object A

I want to add an element of Object A to the `ArrayList`.  I feel like I should be able to do this because Object A is a simpler version of Object B  (or should I say, Object B is a subset of Object A)

But I get `ClassCastException`, what is the solution for this while keeping the extended objects as separate objects.

Comment: if B extends A, shouldn't the list be of type A?

Comment: @FatalError should it? I mean if thats the answer post it

Comment: Show us the code that gives you a `ClassCastException`.

Comment: Your list only accepts B.  Just because every B is an A, it doesn't mean every A is a B.  A could also be a C if that's another subclass of A.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the [Liskov substitution principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) states:

> In a computer program, if S is a subtype of T, then objects of type T
>   may be replaced with objects of type S.

That means if if you have:

```
class Animal {}

class Dog extends Animal {}
```

it makes sense to do:

```
Animal animal = new Dog();
```

but it is wrong to do:

```
Dog dog = new Animal();
```

Which is exactly what you're doing. What you're probably trying to achieve is:

```
List<Animal> list = new ArrayList<Animal>();
list.add(new Animal());
list.add(new Dog());
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have an `ArrayList<B>`, you can add any `B`s and subclasses of `B`. But you can not add `A`s because `A` is no subclass of `B`.

If you want to mix `A`s and `B`s, try `ArrayList<A>`. Here you can add both, because `B` is subclass of `A`. When using polymorphism, always declare your generic data with the most general class as parameter.